# eslint line numbers not showing cmder. how to make line numbers and other text show?

Tags: eslint, cmder

So i was working on a node js project using eslint on the terminal using Cmder.

I have this screenshot.

[image: Image of cmder not showing the line numbers]

If you copy and paste the contents of the terminal. You'll see the line numbers get pasted on a text box.

```
C:\Users\Bangonkali\Desktop\Projects\oneinbox-api (develop -> origin) (api@0.0.118)
λ npm run lint
> api@0.0.118 lint C:\Users\Bangonkali\Desktop\Projects\oneinbox-api
> npm run flow && eslint src/ test/
> api@0.0.118 flow C:\Users\Bangonkali\Desktop\Projects\oneinbox-api
> flow check
Found 0 errors
C:\Users\Bangonkali\Desktop\Projects\oneinbox-api\test\invitation\invite.js
  25:1  error  More than 1 blank line not allowed  no-multiple-empty-lines
✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! api@0.0.118 lint: `npm run flow && eslint src/ test/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the api@0.0.118 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bangonkali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-10T05_20_53_362Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Find 2 empty lines in your code patiently, or do 2 empty lines at the top of your file, select them and do `ctrl+B` to select the another one. (depend of your IDE)

Comment: Or, edit your _.eslintrc_ at the root of your project with a rules `'no-multiple-empty-lines': 0`

Answer (score 0):

I maybe mistaken but I think the OP was about the eslint line numbers (and columns) not appearing in their CMD window but being there if they pasted the text somewhere.

This was happening to me and no amount of searching led anywhere but here.

My solution, in case this happens to anyone else, is to use either PowerShell or Windows-Terminal (in either CMD or PS mode).